# Integrating Inverse square root of a cubic polynomial

Tags: definite-integrals, cubics, elliptic-integrals

I am interested in integrals of the following form:

$\int\limits_{0}^{M} \left( -x^3 +bx^2 -\omega \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \,dx  \, ,$

where $b, \omega>0$, and $M$ is one of the roots of the polynomial ($x=0$ is not a root). I used the trigonometric method to find all three real roots of this polynomial, but have not found any good way/closed form expression for this integral.

Comment: I think you'll find everything you need and more here: http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap3.pdf You're welcome.

Comment: The result will be in terms of elliptic *integrals* and not elliptic functions; similarly, integrals like $\int\left(a+bx+cx^2\right)^{-\frac12}\mathrm dx$ are expressible in terms of inverse trigonometric functions and logarithms, not trigonometric functions and exponentials. In any event, there is a standard reduction algorithm in Abramowitz and Stegun that you might want to look into.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the terminology